# SVN - Overwrite trunk with another branch while maintaining commit history

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I am currently using SVN for my project.

I have  /trunk and I have /BranchA (which was originally branched off trunk)

I want to completely overwrite /trunk with /BranchA , however I want the keep all the old /trunk revision history.

What is the best way(best practice) to achieve this ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could just use BranchA as the new trunk. The trunk is really just a branch, so they are effectively the same. If you want BranchA to be called "trunk", then use the `svn move` command to move the contents of the trunk and then rename BranchA to trunk.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do need to keep BranchA as is , so not sure I can use svn move in this case.

Comment: Then use svn copy to create a copy of BranchA and then use svn move and then rename the copy to trunk.